# optimize a query in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, select, optimization, groupwise-maximum

Here is my system:

```
Linux Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
MySQL 5.7
```

I have a query (below) that is taking too long to complete.

It is taking as long at 9 seconds to complete.  That is an untenable amount of time for a user when waiting for a web page to complete loading.

Also, the dataset is large and growing.  The events table has 250,000 rows.  I tend to add 1200 to 1800 rows per day.

To help in optimization, I would like to add indexes and such, but am stumped about how (and if) I can do that with the derived/joined select query I have.

Here is my query.  (Anyone know how to limit the width of the output so that we don't have to scroll to the right to see the full line?)

```
mysql> explain select OUTSIDE.ownerUID as Owner, 
  OUTSIDE.propUID as Property, 
  OUTSIDE.camname as 'Camera Name', 
  OUTSIDE.direction as Direction, 
  OUTSIDE.camtimestamp as 'Event Time', 
  convert_tz(now(),'UTC','US/Central') as Now, 
  sec_to_time(convert_tz(now(),'UTC','US/Central') - OUTSIDE.CamTimeStamp) as 'Elapsed Time' 
from events OUTSIDE, 
  (select camname,max(camtimestamp) as maxtimestamp from events group by camname) as INSIDE 
where OUTSIDE.camname = INSIDE.camname 
  AND OUTSIDE.camtimestamp = INSIDE.maxtimestamp;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+----------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys        | key          | key_len | ref                 | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+----------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL   | NULL                 | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                | 263103 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | OUTSIDE    | NULL       | ref   | camtimestamp,camname | camtimestamp | 6       | INSIDE.maxtimestamp |      1 |    99.73 | Using where |
|  2 | DERIVED     | events     | NULL       | index | camname              | camname      | 257     | NULL                | 263103 |   100.00 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+----------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.03 sec)
```

Here are the results of the query:

```
mysql> select OUTSIDE.ownerUID as Owner, 
  OUTSIDE.propUID as Property, 
  OUTSIDE.camname as 'Camera Name', 
  OUTSIDE.direction as Direction, 
  OUTSIDE.camtimestamp as 'Event Time', 
  convert_tz(now(),'UTC','US/Central') as Now, 
  sec_to_time(convert_tz(now(),'UTC','US/Central') - OUTSIDE.CamTimeStamp) as 'Elapsed Time' 
from events OUTSIDE, 
  (select camname,max(camtimestamp) as maxtimestamp from events group by camname) as INSIDE 
where OUTSIDE.camname = INSIDE.camname 
  AND OUTSIDE.camtimestamp = INSIDE.maxtimestamp;
+-------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| Owner | Property | Camera Name | Direction | Event Time          | Now                 | Elapsed Time |
+-------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
|     1 |        1 | wls1        | In        | 2020-01-30 12:27:31 | 2020-01-30 12:29:53 | 00:03:42     |
|     1 |        1 | wls2        | Out       | 2020-01-30 12:25:29 | 2020-01-30 12:29:53 | 00:07:04     |
+-------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
2 rows in set (6.49 sec)
```

==========================================================
Thank you to all who answered the question or commented.  I took Uueerdo's suggestion of a composite index and came up with the following results:

```
mysql> create index CamNameCamTime on events (camname,camtimestamp);

mysql> select OUTSIDE.ownerUID as Owner,
           OUTSIDE.propUID as Property,
           OUTSIDE.camname as 'Camera Name',
           OUTSIDE.direction as Direction,
           OUTSIDE.camtimestamp as 'Event Time',
           convert_tz(now(),'UTC','US/Central') as Now,
           sec_to_time(convert_tz(now(),'UTC','US/Central') - OUTSIDE.CamTimeStamp) as 'Elapsed Time' 
      from events OUTSIDE,
         (select camname,max(camtimestamp) as maxtimestamp 
           from events group by camname) as INSIDE
      where OUTSIDE.camname = INSIDE.camname AND OUTSIDE.camtimestamp = INSIDE.maxtimestamp;
+-------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| Owner | Property | Camera Name | Direction | Event Time          | Now                 | Elapsed Time |
+-------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
|     1 |        1 | wls1        | In        | 2020-01-30 18:43:19 | 2020-01-30 18:44:33 | 00:01:54     |
|     1 |        1 | wls2        | Out       | 2020-01-30 18:41:51 | 2020-01-30 18:44:33 | 00:04:42     |
+-------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select OUTSIDE.ownerUID as Owner,
    ->            OUTSIDE.propUID as Property,
    ->            OUTSIDE.camname as 'Camera Name',
    ->            OUTSIDE.direction as Direction,
    ->            OUTSIDE.camtimestamp as 'Event Time',
    ->            convert_tz(now(),'UTC','US/Central') as Now,
    ->            sec_to_time(convert_tz(now(),'UTC','US/Central') - OUTSIDE.CamTimeStamp) as 'Elapsed Time'
    ->       from events OUTSIDE,
    ->          (select camname,max(camtimestamp) as maxtimestamp
    ->            from events group by camname) as INSIDE
    ->       where OUTSIDE.camname = INSIDE.camname AND OUTSIDE.camtimestamp = INSIDE.maxtimestamp;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys                       | key            | key_len | ref                                | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL   | NULL                                | NULL           | NULL    | NULL                               |    2 |   100.00 | Using where              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | OUTSIDE    | NULL       | ref   | camtimestamp,camname,CamNameCamTime | CamNameCamTime | 263     | INSIDE.camname,INSIDE.maxtimestamp |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  2 | DERIVED     | events     | NULL       | range | camname,CamNameCamTime              | CamNameCamTime | 257     | NULL                               |    2 |   100.00 | Using index for group-by |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Success!

Comment: Adding a composite index on `(camname, camtimestamp)` should help improve the performance of the subquery and the join. Also, while I don't think it would necessarily improve performance, I'd also suggest switching to explicit JOIN syntax rather than continuing to use archaic implicit "comma" joins.

Comment: Uueerdo, your suggestion worked very well!  Please consider answering the question so that I may award you the solution.  See my edit above that summarizes my findings with your solution.

Comment: That's the fastest way to do "groupwise-max", but it does nead that index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL cannot use more than one index on each reference to table in a query, so two simple indexes on `camname` and `camtimestamp` separately is likely to only be of limited usefulness in this scenario. Such indexes would be perfect for selecting records in a date range, or all records for a name; but when searching for max values of every name, a `camname` index would be of questionable usefulness (since it must examine every camtimestamp of every name anyway), and a `camstimestamp` would still necessitate searching every record to make sure all camnames are accounted for (the least camtimestamp could be the only one for a particular camname).

With a composite index on `(camname, camtimestamp)` the max values for each `camname` can be quickly identified in the subquery, and then the index can be used again to pick out the row(s) in the table matching the results of the subquery.

Comment: Since there is a subquery here, I suggest changing your opening sentence from "one index on a table in a query" to "one index per `SELECT`".

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below sql out?

```
 SELECT OUTSIDE.owneruid 
       AS Owner, 
       OUTSIDE.propuid 
       AS Property, 
       OUTSIDE.camname 
       AS 'Camera Name', 
       OUTSIDE.direction 
       AS Direction, 
       OUTSIDE.camtimestamp 
       AS 'Event Time', 
       Convert_tz(Now(), 'UTC', 'US/Central') 
       AS Now, 
       Sec_to_time(Convert_tz(Now(), 'UTC', 'US/Central') - 
       OUTSIDE.camtimestamp)
       AS 'Elapsed Time' 
FROM   events OUTSIDE 

WHERE  OUTSIDE.camtimestamp = (SELECT Max(camtimestamp)
        FROM   events WHERE
        events.camname = OUTSIDE.camname);
```

====================

Original Questor here.  I executed the SQL above and the query never finished.  I finally had to hit CTRL C to get it to end.  I re-checked the db connection and tries other generic queries that completed successfully and retried your SQL above.  It did the same thing.

Here is the EXPLAIN for the query:

```
mysql> explain SELECT OUTSIDE.owneruid
    ->        AS Owner,
    ->        OUTSIDE.propuid
    ->        AS Property,
    ->        OUTSIDE.camname
    ->        AS 'Camera Name',
    ->        OUTSIDE.direction
    ->        AS Direction,
    ->        OUTSIDE.camtimestamp
    ->        AS 'Event Time',
    ->        Convert_tz(Now(), 'UTC', 'US/Central')
    ->        AS Now,
    ->        Sec_to_time(Convert_tz(Now(), 'UTC', 'US/Central') -
    ->        OUTSIDE.camtimestamp)
    ->        AS 'Elapsed Time'
    -> FROM   events OUTSIDE
    ->
    -> WHERE  OUTSIDE.camtimestamp = (SELECT Max(camtimestamp)
    ->         FROM   events WHERE
    ->         events.camname = OUTSIDE.camname);
+----+--------------------+---------+------------+------+------------------------+----------------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys          | key            | key_len | ref                 | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+---------+------------+------+------------------------+----------------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | OUTSIDE | NULL       | ALL  | NULL                   | NULL           | NULL    | NULL                | 264783 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | events  | NULL       | ref  | camname,CamNameCamTime | CamNameCamTime | 257     | lpr.OUTSIDE.camname | 263842 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+--------------------+---------+------------+------+------------------------+----------------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Changing the subquery to be correlated is highly unlikely to help in this case.

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'OUTSIDE.camname' in 'where clause'

Comment: Still no good.  This is what I'm getting.  I tried it twice.  I don't get why the error says what it does.  ======== ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE  OUTSIDE.camtimestamp = (SELECT Max(camtimestamp)
        FROM   events WH' at line 19

Comment: The `,` needs removed from after `OUTSIDE`

Comment: @user3055756: Just added the generic idea, didn't try the query out... Yes please remove the comma as mentioned by Uueerdo

Comment: This formulation _also_ needs the Uueerdo's composite index.

Answer (score 0):

If the suggested comment composite index on (camname, camtimestamp) does not help, this might be a scenario to add a trigger to your database.  If you are always looking for the most recent timestamp for a given camera name, I would add a column to the camera name table such as LastEventID.  Then, during your INSERT into the events table, just issue a simplified

```
update CameraNameTable set 
      LastEventID = EventIDOfRecordJustInserted 
   where 
      CameraName = CameraNameOfEventInserted
```

Then, your query could be as simple as

```
select
      E.*,
      [your additional time, convert value columns]
   from
      CameraTable CT
         JOIN Events E
            on CT.LastEventID = E.ID
```

To prime your camera name table after first adding this new column, you can just

```
Update CameraTable 
      JOIN ( select CamName, max( ID ) maxEventID
                from Events
                group by CamName ) PQ
         on CameraTable.CamName = PQ.CamName
   set LastEventID = PQ.maxEventID
```

Your trigger may add subsecond timing to the insert, but even if you are only doing 2,000 per day, that is only 4 per minute over and 8 hour day.  I would not see that as anything significant.  Your table will always be updated as soon as the next event ID record is inserted so your query never needs to keep applying max() and joining.  You are joining based on an exact ID which would be part of an index and only be 1:1 match.

Comment: I like this approach.  And the more I am learning about the limitations of MySQL, I understand that this may be necessary in some cases.  The composite index suggestion above worked.  It look my query time to fractions of a second.